# Bash script - grep output

Tags: bash, curl, grep, wget

I need an output for multiple grep commands.

patterns: ([^"#]+)

```
wget -q -O - http://www.site1.com  | grep -o -E -m 1 'site1content = "([^"#]+)"'
wget -q -O - http://www.site2.com  | grep -o -E -m 1 'site2content"([^"#]+)"
.........
```

Output file:

```
http://www.site1.com***pattern
http://www.site2.com***pattern
```

Comment: What is the output of `wget -q -O - http://www.site1.com` and what do you like to have in the output file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just redirect the output of your commands to a file.

```
wget -q -O - http://www.site1.com  | grep -o -E -m 1 'site1content = "([^"#]+)"' > output.txt
wget -q -O - http://www.site2.com  | grep -o -E -m 1 'site2content"([^"#]+)"' >> output.txt
```

`>` overwrites old content and `>>` appends to the end of the file.

Edit:

Not pretty but a quick and dirty solution might be

```
echo 'http://www.site1.com***'`wget -q -O - http://www.site1.com  | grep -o -E -m 1 'site1content = "([^"#]+)"'` > output.txt
```

(untested)

Comment: thanks for ">>" but output has only "pattern" i need http://www.site1.com***pattern

Comment: I edited my answer because I struggled with the formatting in this comment

Comment: thank you very much :) it works. it is not dirty it is great :)

Answer (score 0):

As is the output you got from the above commends consists only of the pattern found because of the -o parameter:

http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-o

I suggest using the above site for an explanation.